# Taxonomy term translation

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I am working on a multi lingual site. I had installed the i18n (Internationalization). I wanted to get the taxonomy terms translated. But I was not able to do so. 
In the translation mode I had chosen " Localize. Terms are common for all languages, but their name and description may be localized. " 
Can anybody help me please...

Answer (score 1):

It's not like, it's un-translatable. You have to render it on some page and then clear your cache and search in "{you-domain}/admin/config/regional/translate/translate" interface.

Comment: The translated taxonomy terms are listed here the 
Translate interface page that you mentioned. But I am not able to view it in the taxonomy page.

Comment: How and where you are displaying localized taxonomy terms. i mean is it through a view?

Comment: My real task is to pass the translated terms through web-service.